# (Re)installing PHP on Mac OS X

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I've been trying to set up a local development environment on my Mac running 10.7.5 which would include PHP 5.4, Symfony and MySql.

To this end I've been following the instructions at url below to install a new version of PHP using Homebrew at the location of /usr/local/bin/php:
http://justinhileman.info/article/reinstalling-php-on-mac-os-x/

I've had to use this method to get the intl extension needed by Symfony.

So, I've gotten PHP installed, but I have 3 outstanding issues I'm not able to see.

1) How do I change the path that Apache is looking for PHP in? I don't know how to find my .bashrc file (as Justin explains in his post). If I do 'which php', I see that apache is not looking at the new version I just installed

```
    /usr/bin/php
```

Instead of /usr/local/bin/php

2) Once I get Apache pointing to the correct path, what folder would I actually install Symfony in? And where do I put my .php files for the site?

3) What URL will I use to view these new files once I resolve step 1 & 2.

I am new to command line and this is a lot more confusing than just dumping files in ~/me/Sites, but I'm trying and your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use MAMP?

Comment: MAMP doesn't come with the intl.so extension (this is required for the symfony installation). And trying to find/figure out how to get that working wasn't working for me either. So I tried a different route.

Comment: Ok, always restart before asking a question. Restart fixed question 1, but 2&3 remain a mystery. However, after downloading the homebrew formula, I now have the intl.so extension that I can copy into the MAMP installation. So Symfony is now working in MAMP. An answer to 2 & 3 would be educational but not critical at this point. So, I'll wait a couple of days to close this in case anyone answers.